# What determines nomadic clan land demand?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Just started out playing as a nomad in 9th century (the Old Gods bookmark). I immediately started conquering more land for my Khaganate and discovered that clans will often demand so much land that you must make them more powerful than yourself before they become satisfied. This effectively leaves me with two choices. Grant them that much land, decreasing the probability of revolt but strengthening the clans and thus increasing the chances of it succeeding once they revolt. Or two, don't grant them land and live with the higher probability of a revolt but keep yourself stronger and thus decrease probability of it succeeding.

However, I would rather not have this additional instability. Hence, what determines how much land the clans demand? Is this something that can be mitigated?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question but splitting clans to make more clans is a good way to give away land without making any one rival too strong.

Comment: Right, but my clan number is also maximum

Comment: So after a bit of expansion the amount of land that I am able to hold has increased as well as the number of clans that I am allowed to have. So my guess is that the max number of clans is some number * the number of provinces and the max number of provinces you can have is some proportion (less than 1/2) of total provinces you own (just a guess, not verified in any way). Explains the observation that early game with only one vassal clan the game is not allowing you to be stronger than the one other clan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the actual question as per the CK2 Wiki

`The clans will demand a certain amount of land from the ruler that is dependent on the total number of nomadic counties, once the clan limit rises above 1. This demand is 2 at 5 nomadic counties, 3 at 6 nomadic counties, 4 at 7 or 8 nomadic counties, and 66% of the number of nomadic counties, rounding up, thereafter.`

Regarding strategy and how to manage the distribution:

 
Take note that this land can be distributed /unevenly/ amongst your clans, using the blood oath feature (which gives a large sentiment boost as well as relation boost with a single clan, use this on your strongest clan) as well as focusing on keeping your strong clans happy will allow you to stay stable.

Make sure to assasinate the clan leaders that are ambitious or that have low opinion of you, these are the leaders that will want to declare indepdence or revolt. 

In a worst case situation you can either absorb them back and create a new clan from the land you take back.

Comment: Nice, thanks. When I was playing this Blood Oath didn't exist yet. Sounds like they added some cool new features for nomadic play. Thanks for taking the time to answer a very old question.